# Quotient of Polish topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, linear-transformations, quotient-spaces

Let $X$, $Y$ be Polish topological vector spaces, i.e. vector spaces with a complete metric for which the addition and the scalar multiplication are continuous. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a continuous, linear, and surjective mapping.

> **Question 1.** Is $X/\ker(f)$ a Polish space? (Here $\ker(f)$ denotes the kernel of the linear transformation $f$.)
>
> **Question 2.** Is the restriction $f|_{X/\ker(f)}$ a Borel isomorphism, i.e. both $f|_{X/\ker(f)}$ and $f|_{X/\ker(f)}^{-1}$ are Borel measurable?

Comment: What do you mean by linear mapping since $X$ and $Y$ are only metric spaces?

Comment: Sorry, I hope that now is clearer.

Comment: Do you know the appropriate facts for Banach spaces? Did you check if the proofs work in this case?

Comment: Not yet, I will do it asap. Thanks for the comment.